# Break [q0/q1] into [q1,q2]

Tags: java, regex, linked-list

I have LinkedList which contains let's say an element of type [q0/q1].
I would like to convert that to a LinkedList that contains the same element but they should be in [q0,q1] -> the size of the linked list to be 2 as opposed to the [q0/q1] which has a size of one.

Could you suggest me how to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Please be more explicit.  Are you talking about strings here?  i.e. Do you have a string of the form `"[q0/q1]"`?  If not, then what does your notation mean?  Are you talking about rational numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guess

```
    LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();
    ll.add("[q0/q1]");

    // since you tagged it [regex] :-)
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)/(.*?)\\]");

    LinkedList<String> ll2 = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (String pair : ll) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(pair);
        if (m.matches()) {
            ll2.add(m.group(1));
            ll2.add(m.group(2));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(ll2);  // prints [q0, q1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that q0/q1 is a String input.
Then the code will be like

```
LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();

ll.push( "q0/q1" );

ll = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(ll.pop().split("/")));
```